# Как корректно отображать файлы с русским названием, при открытии созданного zip архива?

Tags: кодировка, zip, php

Парни, привет!
Как создать zip архив средствами php при помощи класса `ZipArchive` таким образом, чтобы при открытии этого архива, названия файлов, написанные по-русски, расположенных внутри него отображались корректно?

```
$zip_filename = "/tmp/" . microtime() . "-" . md5($formattedMessage);

if (is_writable("/tmp"))
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($zip_filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE)
    {
        // ... логика, когда не удалось создать файл архива
    }
    else
    {
        $zip->addFromString("Прайс.html", $formattedMessage);
        $zip->close();
        $mail->AddAttachment($zip_filename, "Прайс.zip");
    }
}
```

В приведенном примере архив создается, все ок, но вместо Прайс.html выводятся <символы_вопроса>.html.

OS Ubuntu 12.10, Apache/2.2.22 , Php 5.4.6

Comment: @nolka, мне всегда казалось, что данные всегда отображаются корректно (относительно) - соответственно вопрос в том, чем и как отображаете их Вы, что считаете некорректным. А учитывая что у Вас Ubuntu, так это проблема архиватора(насколько я осведомлён).

Comment: В винде тоже символы вопроса вместо русских букв.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@nolka](/users/8440/nolka)](/users/8440/nolka), решение оказалось простым
Заменить **"Прайс.html"** на

```
iconv('windows-1251', 'CP866//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', "Прайс.html")
```

Comment: Я не понимаю, как работает iconv(). У меня система в utf-8, в винде - windows-1251. Зачем конверсию производить из win1251 в cp866? O_o

Comment: @nolka, zip-архивы принимают имена в DOS OEM. Тут английская кодовая страница cp437, соответсвенно кириллическая - cp866

Comment: Так а почему тогда конвертирование происходит из cp1251, а не из юникода?

Comment: @nolka, этот вариант сработал в хрюше на работе, unix'овой системы под рукой нет:) Вы по своему желанию можете варьировать значение кодировки, в зависимости от того, что у Вас на сервере